# Pyramid set up on a shared host with fastcgi gives the .fcgi file back to the browser

Tags: python, apache, .htaccess, pyramid, fastcgi

Can anyone help me with the procedure of setting up the production server on a shared host with pyramid? I searched for a whole day trying to make this work but nothing works.

I'm having trouble on writing the .htaccess and index.fcgi files. I tried to combine these tutorials; [1](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/django-with-fastcgi#shared-reseller), [2](https://wiki.hostsharing.net/index.php?title=Pyramid), [3](http://turbogears.org/2.1/docs/main/Deployment/FastCGI.html), [4](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/modwsgi/) to figure it out but when I visit the website I see the contents of index.fcgi instead of the application. I've done these steps;

1. Created a virtual environment for python in the home directory and activated it:

   ```
    mkdir temp; cd temp
    curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-12.0.7.tar.gz
    gzip -cd virtualenv-12.0.7.tar.gz |tar xf -
    cd virtualenv-12.0.7
    python2.7 setup.py install --user
    cd ~
    ~/.local/bin/virtualenv pyramid --python=python2.7
    source ~/pyramid/bin/activate
   ```
2. Installed pyramid in the virtual environment.

   ```
   pip install pyramid
   ```
3. Created a test project;

   ```
   pcreate -s starter myProject
   cd myProject
   python setup.py install
   ```
4. Installed flup

   ```
   pip install flup
   ```
5. Created an index.fcgi file in my public_html folder with this content:

   ```
   #!/home3/reyhane/pyramid/bin/python
   import os
   import sys 

   myapp = '/home3/reyhane/myProject'
   inifile = 'production.ini'
   sys.path.insert(0, myapp )

   from paste.deploy import loadapp
   wsgi_app = loadapp('config:' + myapp + '/' + inifile)
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
       WSGIServer(wsgi_app).run()
   ```
6. Made index.fcgi executable;

   ```
   cd public_html
   chmod +x index.fcgi
   ```

   Its permission is 0755.
7. Modified .htaccess file in public_html folder to:

   ```
   AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
   DirectoryIndex index.fcgi

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.fcgi$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.fcgi/$1 [L]
   AddType "text/html; charset=UTF-8" html
   AddType "text/plain; charset=UTF-8" txt 
   AddCharset UTF-8 .html
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
   ```

So my directory looks like this:

```
    home3/reyhane/
    |-- pyramid
    |-- myProject
    |   |-- myProject
    |   |-- production.ini
    |-- public_html/
    |   |-- index.fcgi
    |   |-- .htaccess
```

It seems that .htaccess file is doing its job because the page is redirected to index.fcgi but there must be a problem with index.fcgi.

Comment: I am not changing the production.ini file. Is there any changes that must be made there?

Comment: What's happening? Is there an error message? Is there anything in logs?

Comment: no there is no error. When I visit the website there is just the plain text format of the contents of index.fcgi . I don't know how to see the logs. Because it is not redirected to the web application. i have a view to see the logs of waitress but it doesn't seem to get to that point. @MikkoOhtamaa

Comment: Apache does not how to handle .fcgi file. It thinks it's a plain text file that needs to be send to the user. Either .htaccess is being ignored or `AddHandler` does not work. If it's a shared web host, usually it means that you might not have access to Apache yourself to tell what's going on. But in this case you can contact the support of the hosting company to resolve the situation for you.

Comment: I'm using host gator and FastCGI is supposed to work on their [shared hosts] (https://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/hardware-software/compatible-technologies) They are also supporting Django which is very similar to [pyramid in using fcgi server](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/django-with-fastcgi#shared-reseller)

Comment: If Django works Pyramid should work as well. WSGI is Python standard protocol and used by any Python application on server side.

Comment: I also don't think .htaccess is being ignored because I installed wordpress on the server and changed that .htaccess file. What is AddHandler?

Comment: Prefer to Gator's Django instructions, copy them and just drop in your application and its .fcgi file. Using their instructions you should get to the point where .fcgi file is executed, not served.

Comment: I tried to do it step by step but couldn't make it work. I have not worked with django before.

Comment: That's why it is better to follow instructions from Gator, because their instructions should 100% work with their hosting. If these instructions do not work then you can contact their support. Of you can just cross-reference to their instructions and figure out how they are different from your .htaccess etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have following htaccess file working fine:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ YOUR_APP_NAME.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

And FCGI file:

```
#$HOME/YOUR_APP_NAME/bin/python
import sys
from paste.deploy
import loadapp
from flup.server.fcgi_fork import WSGIServer
app = loadapp('config:$HOME/YOUR_APP_NAME/src/production.ini')
server = WSGIServer(app)
server.run()
```

I described Pyramid deployment in such case in article ['Run Pyramid on Shared Hosting'](http://mobilepro.pl/blog-o-tworzeniu-stron-internetowych/46_Run-Pyramid-on-Shared-Hosting). I hope it will be usefull for you.

Comment: After contacting hostgator, I found out that as @MikkoOhtamaa had predicted, the apache handler had problem. So the main problem was from their side.  They said fastCGI was not fully enabled on some of their new servers where my site resided. After they fixed the handler, I followed my steps again but my index.fcgi did not work so I used yours and now everything works prefect. -Thanks